# moment.js isAfter performance

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have my dates converted to moment.js, and now I want to compare it with another date ('now' in this case).

Just a plain compare with a date object seems to be **a lot** faster than using moment.js `isAfter` function.

- Will this simple compare work in all locales?
- Am I missing something here?
- Is there a very specific reason why isAfter seems to create a new moment object instead of taking a shortcut when it's a `Date` object?

All my dates are in UTC.

```js
function executeTests() {
  isAfterTest();
  compareTest();
}

function isAfterTest() {
  console.time('isAfterTest');

  var now = new Date();
  var dateOfBirth = moment('2000-01-01');

  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var x = dateOfBirth.isAfter(now);
  }

  console.timeEnd('isAfterTest');
}

function compareTest() {
  console.time('compareTest');

  var now = new Date();
  var dateOfBirth = moment('2000-01-01');

  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var x = dateOfBirth > now;
  }

  console.timeEnd('compareTest');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment-with-langs.js"></script>
<button onclick="executeTests();">Run Test</button>
```

Results:

```
isAfterTest: 3754.000ms (index):32
compareTest: 24.000ms
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/t4grs0p7/2/

Comment: is it even correct to compare a `Date` and a `Moment` using that operator?

Comment: I made a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/momentjs-isafter-performance) for you. Feel free to tweak it if I didn't represent your test cases correctly.

Comment: I have not really a clue goat, but it seems to work :| that's point. I'm wondering if I'm missing some essential stuff that I'm not taking into account atm.

Comment: @goat: it seems to work as far as I can see. the < operator seems to convert both objects to amount of ms since epoch through their valueOf() functions.

Comment: It's quite impressive how slow the isAfter method actually is! Definitely not useful in lists of data. I just thought I'd suggest you write up your result as an answer and accept it so that it might make things easier for Google and other future browsers who come across the question. Cheers

Comment: I got `2028.22ms` and `13.48ms` as the average after 10 runs in Chrome v39.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the documentation http://momentjs.com/docs/ the isAfter method accepts different types of Date format:

```
moment().isAfter(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
```

This means it needs to do type checking and then convert it to a date object before running the calculation.

One way you could reduce this impact would be to pass in a Moment object as the comparison date:

```
function isAfterTest() {
    console.time('isAfterTest');

    var now = moment();
    var dateOfBirth = moment('2000-01-01');

    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        var x = dateOfBirth.isAfter(now);
    }

    console.timeEnd('isAfterTest');
}
```

I created a fiddle to compare, but that doesn't seem to improve it much at all:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/t4grs0p7/7/

Looking at your version I believe you should be using valueOf() method to compare the values:

```
window.compareTest2 = function() {
    console.time('compareTest2');

    var now = moment().valueOf();
    var dateOfBirth = moment('2000-01-01').valueOf();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 50000; i++ )
        var x = dateOfBirth > now;

    console.timeEnd('compareTest2');
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/t4grs0p7/8/

Comment: I just updated the code to use MomentJs 2.9.0 **and** use the minified version. **results are impressive!!** http://jsfiddle.net/t4grs0p7/9/ (if you switch back to 2.7.0 it's about 10x slower)

Comment: Yup. MomentJS 2.7.0 would clone the moment argument that got passed into isBefore and isAfter, leading to really abismal performance. Upgrading MomentJS fixes things nicely.